# How do I do Lua Breakpoint/Step Debugging into a C library loaded into Lua

Tags: lua, luajit

I have a Lua (5.4.3) script running via VSCode and I'm using the excellent extension  "Lua Helper" v0.2.1 by yinfei. This provides excellent breakpoint and step debugging in a Lua script.

But, as might be expected, it steps over calls to a loaded C library.

Can anyone suggest how stepping into the C library could be accomplished?

Of course, I can write a C main.c test harness to test the C library independently, but just interested if there are any other established ways of debugging from the Lua script, other than printf() statements!!

Comment: Does it not work to just set a breakpoint in the C library with the regular C debugger?

Comment: This Visual Studio extension supports stepping from C into Lua: [LuaDkmDebugger](https://github.com/WheretIB/LuaDkmDebugger)